# Remove certain no. of characters before and after each line in a TXT file with bash or python

Tags: python, bash, text

I was wondering if there is a way to remove desired no. of characters before and after each line in a text file using bash or python

I am trying to remove first 5 characters and last 2 characters in each line in this case

file.txt

```
(2, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)')
(3, 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/register')
```

desired_file.txt

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/register
```

I've tried to look for similar questions unfortunately none of'em worked for me

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Try `sed "s/.* '//; s/'.*//" file.txt` or `awk -F "'" '{print $2}' file.txt`

Comment: `sed -E 's/^.{5}(.*)..$/\1/' file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try this code. It seems like a simple fix but I wouldn't recommend this since it restricts how you parse.

```
input_file = "input.txt"
output_file = "output.txt"

with open(input_file, "r") as infile, open(output_file, "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        trimmed_line = line[5:-3]
        outfile.write(trimmed_line + "\n")
```

Instead I would recommend your code be based on the word http and end with ')
As per the code below:

```
input_file = "input.txt"
output_file_1 = 'output1.txt'

with open(input_file, "r") as infile, open(output_file_1, "w") as outfile1:
    for line in infile:
        start_index = line.find("http")
        end_index = line.rfind("')")
        trimmed_line = line[start_index:end_index]
        outfile1.write(trimmed_line + "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than removing a number of leading and trailing characters you could look at this another way. What you want is the sequence of characters between single quotes. You could extract those with a regular expression.

For example:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"(?<=').+?(?=')")
s = "(2, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)')"
print(*p.findall(s))
```

**Output:**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)
```

Comment: Works also with grep: `grep -oP "(?<=').+?(?=')"`

Comment: Or `awk -F "'" '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can slice a string between 5th and two from the end like so

```
print(line[5:len(line)-2])
```

But what happens if the number is more than one digit? I think you should consider splitting each line on commas, then remove trailing parenthesis (`rstrip`), then you can pass second element to `ast.literal_eval` to get a string

Or, you could fix whatever process generates this file to get a more parsable format